# How to prove the the addition of tangent is the same as the multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

If A,B,C are angles of a triangle show that:

$$\tan A+ \tan B+\tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C $$

I've tried this many times but I cannot seem to prove it, can someone show me how to solve this problem?

Comment: use the facts that $A+B+C=\pi$, $\tan(\pi-x)=-\tan x$, and the addition formula for tangent
$$
\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}
$$

Comment: @FelipeZC: Do you understand?

Comment: Yeah, thanks man

Answer (score 4):

set $t_a=\tan A$ etc.

for any pair of angles $A,B$ we have
$$
\tan(A+B) = \frac{t_a+t_b}{1-t_at_b}
$$
so for any three angles $A,B,C$:
$$
\tan(A+B+C)= \frac{ \frac{t_a+t_b}{1-t_at_b} +t_c}{1-\frac{t_a+t_b}{1-t_at_b}t_c} $$
$$
=\frac{t_a+t_b+t_c -t_at_bt_c}{1-(t_at_b+t_bt_c+t_ct_a)} \tag{1}
$$
if, in addition, we know that:
$$
A+B+C = n\pi \tag{2}
$$
then 
$$
\tan(A+B+C) = 0
$$
for a planar triangle (2) holds with $n=1$, so in (1) the numerator must be zero, giving:
$$
\tan A + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
0 = \tan 180^\circ = \tan (A+B+C)
$$
Apply to the line above the formula for the tangent of a sum of two numbers.  You can take the two numbers to be $A$ and $B+C$, so
$$
\tan(A+(B+C)) = \frac{\tan A + \tan(B+C)}{1-\tan A\tan(B+C)}.
$$
Then apply it again to $\tan(B+C)$.  Do the routine simplifications.  You get a fraction.  A fraction is zero only if the numerator is zero.  The identity you're trying to prove just says the numerator of this fraction is zero.